# I would like to find consecutive numbers in column A and column B in python (pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to find consecutive numbers in column A and Column B in python, Column A should be ascending but Column B is descending. I am attaching an example file.

Input file

| nucleotide | Pos_A | Pos_B |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos102 | 20 | 102 |  |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos102 | 19 | 102 |  |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos101 | 20 | 101 |  |
| Connection_Pos18_Pos102 | 18 | 102 |  |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos101 | 19 | 101 |  |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos100 | 20 | 100 |  |
| Connection_Pos17_Pos102 | 17 | 102 |  |
| Connection_Pos18_Pos101 | 18 | 101 |  |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos100 | 19 | 100 |  |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos99 | 20 | 99 |  |
| Connection_Pos16_Pos102 | 16 | 102 |  |
| Connection_Pos17_Pos101 | 17 | 101 |  |
| Connection_Pos18_Pos100 | 18 | 100 |  |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos99 | 19 | 99 |  |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos98 | 20 | 98 |  |
| Connection_Pos15_Pos102 | 15 | 102 |  |
| Connection_Pos16_Pos101 | 16 | 101 |  |
| Connection_Pos17_Pos100 | 17 | 100 |  |
| Connection_Pos18_Pos99 | 18 | 99 |  |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos98 | 19 | 98 |  |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos97 | 20 | 97 |  |
| Connection_Pos14_Pos102 | 14 | 102 |  |
| Connection_Pos15_Pos101 | 15 | 101 |  |
| Connection_Pos16_Pos100 | 16 | 100 |  |

Output:

| nucleotide | Pos_A | Pos_B | Consecutive ID | Consecutive Number (Size) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos102 | 20 | 102 | 101 | 1 |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos102 | 19 | 102 | 100 | 2 |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos101 | 20 | 101 | 100 | 2 |
| Connection_Pos18_Pos102 | 18 | 102 | 99 | 3 |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos101 | 19 | 101 | 99 | 3 |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos100 | 20 | 100 | 99 | 3 |
| Connection_Pos17_Pos102 | 17 | 102 | 98 | 4 |
| Connection_Pos18_Pos101 | 18 | 101 | 98 | 4 |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos100 | 19 | 100 | 98 | 4 |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos99 | 20 | 99 | 98 | 4 |
| Connection_Pos16_Pos102 | 16 | 102 | 97 | 5 |
| Connection_Pos17_Pos101 | 17 | 101 | 97 | 5 |
| Connection_Pos18_Pos100 | 18 | 100 | 97 | 5 |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos99 | 19 | 99 | 97 | 5 |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos98 | 20 | 98 | 97 | 5 |
| Connection_Pos15_Pos102 | 15 | 102 | 96 | 6 |
| Connection_Pos16_Pos101 | 16 | 101 | 96 | 6 |
| Connection_Pos17_Pos100 | 17 | 100 | 96 | 6 |
| Connection_Pos18_Pos99 | 18 | 99 | 96 | 6 |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos98 | 19 | 98 | 96 | 6 |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos97 | 20 | 97 | 96 | 6 |
| Connection_Pos14_Pos102 | 14 | 102 | 95 | 7 |
| Connection_Pos15_Pos101 | 15 | 101 | 95 | 7 |
| Connection_Pos16_Pos100 | 16 | 100 | 95 | 7 |
| Connection_Pos17_Pos99 | 17 | 99 | 95 | 7 |
| Connection_Pos18_Pos98 | 18 | 98 | 95 | 7 |
| Connection_Pos19_Pos97 | 19 | 97 | 95 | 7 |
| Connection_Pos20_Pos96 | 20 | 96 | 95 | 7 |

Comment: Please include in your post a picture or example of what you would like your data to look like afterwards.

Comment: first sort them in ascending and descending order as per your requirement. Then check for shift() and shift(-1).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: So, I'm assuming `'Consecutive ID'` and `'Consecutive Number (Size)'` are not included in your data and what you are trying to calculate.  Is that correct.

Comment: @piRSquared Yes 'Consecutive ID' and 'Consecutive Number (Size) are not included.

Comment: Can you please post the clear text version of the data instead of images please

Comment: Also, can you please explain through few examples how you arrived at the numbers for consecutive id and consecutive number sizes

Comment: @JoeFerndz: The output file was created by senior in C++,  in which he created id for each unique consecutive numbers (ID is basically the numbers in Pos_B with -1)

Comment: This post has changed back and forth.  I no longer think I understand.

Comment: Analyzing the data further, I think i understood the ask. Not sure if this is as easy as it looks. You are looking for pattern of data (ascending & descending) on two columns. Interesting problem and i upvoted it.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about something like this using a "fuzzy" form of groupby: https://thingspython.wordpress.com/2020/11/11/fuzzy-groupby-unusual-restaurant-part-ii/

Answer (score 2):

Do it one by one then `groupby` with `ngroup`

```
s1 = df.Pos_A.diff().le(0).cumsum()
s2 = df.Pos_B.diff().ge(0).cumsum()
df['out'] = df.groupby([s1,s2]).ngroup()+1
Out[452]: 
0     1
1     2
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     4
7     4
8     4
9     4
10    5
11    5
12    5
13    5
14    5
15    6
16    6
17    6
18    6
19    6
20    6
21    7
22    7
23    7
24    7
25    7
26    7
27    7
dtype: int64
```